# win text will not disappear

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a tilting maze game in Unity where you have to tilt a ball to a specific point in the maze. Now the following code I've made is supposed to trigger a "You Win!" text when the ball interacts with a block in the maze. The problem is, the text won't appear at all. Please analyze it, a tell me any possible solutions to my problem.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {



public Text countText;
public Text winText;

private Rigidbody rb;
private int count;



void Start ()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    count = 0;
    countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();
    winText.text = "";
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Up"))
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = count + 1;
        SetCountText();


    }
}

void SetCountText()

{ 
    countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();

    if (count >= 1)

        winText.text = "You Win!";
}
```

Comment: have you used the debugger..? perhaps you need to call a Refresh method on the UI if one exist or something similar to `Application.DoEvents()`

Comment: "Like it" but not it.  `Application.DoEvents()` just might be [the devil](https://blog.codinghorror.com/is-doevents-evil/).

Comment: try setting the `countText.text = string.Empty;`  prior to setting the new value for countText and winText

Comment: Won't appear, or won't disappear? The title and body of your question are contradictory.

Comment: Is putting a Debug.Log inside the if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Up")) statement shows up?